# C# Windows Phone - Custom Pushpins with related data

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1, bing-maps, custom-component, pushpin

I'm trying to add a map to my app.
The map needs to show customized pins (from png images)
And each of them needs somehow to contain a ID that I will use to retrieve data from a database.

So basically when the user taps on them, on the related event, I need to be able to retrieve that ID...

I've been trying two options:

---

First one is the one described on Microsoft website:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsphonetrainingcourse_usingbingmapslab_topic3.aspx

That works creating customized pins....but I can't find a way to store any data in them that I will be able to retrieve later on. Cause when I create a pin I work on a PushpinModel, but when the click event happens on one of them the sender is not the PushpinModel anymore, but just a Pushpin.

---

Second one is the one described on many websites and tutorials, that basically suggests to create a Pushpin with transparent background and a picture as content or foreground.
(e.g. http://www.geekchamp.com/articles/windows-phone-drawing-custom-pushpins-on-the-map-control-what-options-do-we-have)

With that one I can surely store the ID and retreive it on sender var when the pushpin is tapped.....but the picture completely stands on a wrong position on the map, since it doesn't actually start from the location point but appears only on "content" rectangle of the transparent pushpin.

So, to recap:
1st option: customized pin shows on the right spot, but I can't retrieve the ID.
2nd option: I can retrieve the ID, but the customized pin doesn't show on the right spot.

Any idea on how to solve one of the 2 problems?
Or.....do you have any third option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrive the PushpinModel from the pushpin. If you followed the tutorial you linked, you've created the pushpin by binding a list of PushpinModel to the MapItemsControl. In that case, the PushpinModel is stored in the `DataContext` property of the pushpin. To retrieve it from the click event of the pushpin, first cast the `sender` parameter, then the `DataContext` property:

```
var pushpin = (Pushpin)sender;
var model = (PushpinModel)pushpin.DataContext;
```

Comment: uhhh is it? DataContext? nice, thanks! I'll try immediately :)